# Need to declare variables in PS script of another PS script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a PS script abc.ps1 in which i want to declare few variables which exist in script xyz.ps1 and also with abc.ps1 i am running script xyz.ps1 as admin.

Script xyz.ps1 looks like

```
"Code to run $1 $2 $3"
```

Script abc.ps1 lookslike

```
$1 = 123
$2 = 345
$3 = 567
Set-Location -Path "F:\abd\jkl"
Powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell "F:\abd\jkl"; & ".\xyz.ps1"";""
```

I am new to Powershell. Can anybody help me to the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Since you're starting xyz.ps1 as a new elevated process it's not possible to share  with it variables of its parent script. Just pass them as a command line parameter. Or (if elevation is not a mandatory) you can use a dot-sourcing (https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/02/02/exploring-dot-sourcing-in-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively put the variable definitions in a separate script and [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#dot-sourcing-operator-) that in the invoked script.

Comment: @montonero How do i pass the variables as command-line parameters?
I need to run the the abc.ps1 script with elevated privileges
Actually i have to use abc.ps1 script in Jenkins and pass the variables as parameters there

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Tried that, doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. How *exactly* did it "not work", i.e. what behavior did you expect, and what behavior did you observe? How did you verify?

Comment: @darc Parameters are passed according to the Start-Process and powershell.exe description:
`Start-Process [-FilePath] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <String[]>]`
for powershell.exe you could use -File parameter